# Python 2.7 Logging Module not creating files

Tags: python, logging

So I've written some logging into my Python script. Below is the code to set up the FileHandlers.  On my computer when I run my script from the command line, the logging works as expected. I get the "validation_report.log" in the same directory as the directory I am running the script. On my colleague's computer, however, the program runs as expected except nothing is logged the file is not created.

An earlier iteration of this I just opened some files and wrote strings to the file, that worked on both machines.

I have admin rights to my computer, my colleague does not.  Not sure if that is a problem but its a point of information.

```
    report_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    report_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    handler_rl = logging.FileHandler(join(cwd,'validation_report.log'))
    command_line = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s: %(asctime)s %(message)s')

    handler_rl.setFormatter(formatter)
    command_line.setFormatter(formatter)

    report_logger.addHandler(handler_rl)
    report_logger.addHandler(command_line)
```

Comment: How did you get `cwd`?

Comment: sorry, not shown `os.cwd()`  And honestly I just put that in there to see if that was the problem. Before it was just: `logging.FileHandler('validation_report.log')`

Comment: If rights were an issue, you'd get an `IOError` when creating the `FileHandler`. I can't think of anything unless the script is run differently (say a double-click from the desktop manager as opposed to command line). I assume you see logging from the `StreamHandler`... you could print `os.getcwd()` just for fun (grasping at straws here).

Comment: by the way, you don't need `join(cwd,'validation_report.log')` to make the file name absolute. `'validation_report.log'` will be created in the current working directory. You only need to "absolutize" it if you want to use it later and worried that some other bit of code changes directories.

Comment: Well, thanks for thinking about the problem at least.  She's running from the command line also.